# stuck in animating in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to animate the picture so that when the user enters a X and Y offset values, the picture will start at the left upper corner of the window, then moves from left to right, and finally move the picture top down to the final position one pixel at a time.

Here's my code, http://jsfiddle.net/nMdNk/3/

in my javascript, I have:

```
function moveRight() {
    hx = document.getElementById("xval").value;
    imgx = document.getElementById("picture").clientX; //get current X from image
    for (a = 0; a <= imgx; a++;) {

        if (imgx == hx) {
            moveDown();
        } else {
            setTimeOut(moveRight, 1000);
        }
    }
}

function moveDown() {
    hy = document.getElementById("yval").value;
    imgy = document.getElementById("picture").clientY; //get current Y from image
    for (b = 0; b <= imgy; b++;) {

        if (imgy = hy) {
            return; //stop when reach to final destination 
        } else {
            setTimeOut(moveDown, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I'm retrieving the wrong element for the x and y coordinates of the picture but not quite sure. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn’t have a capital `o`, for one.

Comment: Why aren't you declaring your variables?. `var` is _not_ optional. You just create a bunch of global variables.

Comment: Also you're not actually setting the position of the image anywhere. You need to use something like style.top and style.left at some point.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Chrome's inspector or Firefox's firebug to inspect your code for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the code for you and put it in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQTeG/). I made a couple of changes, but not too drastic. The main one was your for loop was unnecessary, and would have resulted in strange behaviour - by calling your functions in setTimeout, the for loops are essentially bypassed. So for each iteration in the for loop, you'd set off a whole new chain of operations via setTimeout. If you didn't have the check (imgx == hx) for example, your script would go on indefinitely, even with the for loop there.

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("picture").style.left = '0px';
    document.getElementById("picture").style.top = '0px';
    moveRight();
}
function moveRight() {
    hx = 1 * document.getElementById("xval").value;
    imgx = document.getElementById("picture").offsetLeft; //get current X from image
    document.getElementById("picture").style.left = (imgx + 1) + 'px';
    if (imgx == hx) {
        moveDown();
    } else {
        setTimeout(moveRight, 10);
    }
}

function moveDown() {
    hy = 1 * document.getElementById("yval").value;
    imgy = document.getElementById("picture").offsetTop; //get current Y from image
    document.getElementById("picture").style.top = (imgy + 1) + 'px';
    if (imgy == hy) {
        return; //stop when reach to final destination 
    } else {
        setTimeout(moveDown, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: may I ask what's the `1 *` for? it seems that the function can run it without it.

Comment: I assume he is making sure the value from the form is an integer instead of a string. It does the same thing as: parseInt(document.getElementById('yva').value,10);

Comment: Ah I thought it wouldn't work without it. Yes as laurencek said, it's to make sure the rest of the code knows it's an integer instead of a string. Because "+" has two meanings, adding and concatenating, I didn't want 1+1 to equal 11.